# Polygon to raster with extent equal to the raster one?

Tags: raster

I need to produce a range of raster layers with the same extents to be able to apply "Weighted overlay". The problem is when converting from polygon to raster the output raster has 1 value for the polygon but Nodata value for the rest of the extent. How could I manage to get a data value instead for this area?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: please indicate the software that you want to use. Also, 1) don't you mean "extent" instead of "extension" ?  2) what value would yu expect when you don't have polygons ?

Comment: @Luke: I´ve tried that but converted values only cover the immediate rectangular boundary of the polygons (previously converted using "Polygon to Raster")  leaving part of the area of interest with Nodata value.
Please see image attached for more clarity.
https://pasteboard.co/HT7oqXi.png

Comment: @radouxju I am using ArcGIS. In this case I´m after a restricted area delimited by the polygons which are contain within an area of interest. So I would need a value for the polygon and another for the rest of the extent. P.S: yes, i ment "extent" apologies.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the [Polygon to Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/polygon-to-raster.htm) tool, ensure you specify an appropriate extent in the tool [environment settings](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/polygon-to-raster.htm#GUID-21792F00-9D90-4FBE-9F68-90F98802B802), such as the extent of your study area.

[image]

Then convert your raster NoData to 0 (or whatever value you want) using the raster calculator with an expression like:

```
Con(IsNull("your raster"), 0, "your raster")
```

Comment: Also set the snap raster environment, this will ensure the exported raster aligns perfectly with the other raster; if the extent, snap raster and cell size are all set to the other raster it will have the same origin and cell dimensions (rows and columns). From the question though it sounds like the OP wants there to be *real values* in the NoData area, it would help if they could draw a picture of what they have and what they want.